# How to create a database that is a randomized subset of another db (mysql)?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL-DB containing 2 tables "records" and "features" linked by one foreign key in features referring to the primary key "id" in records.

My goal is to create a randomized but fixed subset of the data in the DB for machinelearning that can be dumped and hashed for reproducability.

So I thought it would be handy if I could draw a randomized subset of the data and move it to a seperate DB.

Is that possible and if yes: how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another column to the table.  It could be `DOUBLE` or `INT` or `BIGINT`, depending on size, etc.  Populate it with some function of `RAND()`.  Also, index the column.

Now you can fetch rows that are consecutive in this new column; they will be "random" from the point of view of the original data.  And it will be reproducible.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
    WHERE myrand > $x
    ORDER BY myrand  LIMIT 200000;
```

In this case I am allowing `$x` to give you different subsets of the table -- each reproducible.  You would need to adjust $x to avoid overlapping between one subset and another (if that matters).

Note:  I did not copy the data over, merely fetched directly from the original data.  This *may* be an added benefit.  Or it simply gives you the way to 'copy' the rows.

Comment: This is MUCH butter than my approach; so I will accept that as the answer as it solves the underlying problem elengantly! I never had the idea to modify the tables themself to make my problem easier...so:Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Wolfone - You are welcome.  I enjoy "thinking out of the box".  Other approaches to related problems:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found a solution that at least serves the main goal, but it is not a very direct solution and quite slow as I am far from proficiency with RDBMS so if anyone can give a better answer that doesn't involve so many single steps I will accept that but until then, this is what I ended up doing:

1) As backup of a randomized fixed sample set was the greater goal, it was sufficient to first store the information in seperate tables in the same DB so I created two tables *records_rand* and *features_rand* of the same structure as the originals. (How to copy entire tables to another DB can be found easily via web-search.)

2) Draw random sample from the "main-record-table" and insert into the new *record_rand*-table.

```
INSERT INTO records_rand SELECT 
*
FROM
    records_agg
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 200000;
```

3) Loop over the newly inserted records and fill the new feature-table with the associated feature-data (this was quite timeconsuming >1h to copy around 1.8M rows out of around 10M rows):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS copyFeatures;
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE copyFeatures()
BEGIN
DECLARE currentId INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM records_rand INTO n;
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO 
  SET currentId = (SELECT id FROM records_rand LIMIT i,1);  
  INSERT INTO features_rand SELECT * FROM features_agg WHERE currentId=record_id;
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
End;
;;

DELIMITER ;

CALL copyFeatures();
```

( 4) MySQL-Workbench allows choosing of tables which should be exported in a dump so it wasn't really necessary anymore to move the data to a new DB. )